# Rafu al-Yadayn hadith

Tags: hadith, authenticity

What is the status in terms of authenticity of hadith about not doing nothing raful ya den in Musannaf ibn abi Shaybah (purely on isnad basis)
Like
Ibn Umar and Ali(raziallauanhu) not doing it
And students of Ali and ibn Mas'ud not doing it
and other hadith

> حدثنا وكيع وأبو أسامة عن شعبة عن أبي إسحاق قال: كان أصحاب عبد اللَّه وأصحاب علي لا يرفعون أيديهم إلا في افتتاح الصلاة، قال وكيع: ثم لا يعودون
> حدثنا يحيى بن آدم عن حسن بن عياش عن عبد الملك بن أبجر عن الزبير بن عدي عن إبراهيم عن الأسود قال: صليت مع عمر فلم يرفع يديه في شيء من صلاته إلا حين افتتح الصلاة ([Source](https://shamela.ws/book/333/2874))

> حدثنا وكيع عن أبي بكر بن عبد اللَّه بن (قطاف) (١) النهشلي عن عاصم بن كليب عن أبيه: أن عليا كان يرفع يديه إذا افتتح الصلاة ثم لا يعود (٢). ([Source](https://shamela.ws/book/333/2862))
> Etc..

Comment: You are asking while you have a statement of authenticity in each of the links you are sharing? First link says it is sahih صحيح, second says: it is hassan because of the status of abu Bakr ibn al-Qattaf as a muhadith حسن لحال أبي بكر بن قطاف